# Не открывается сайт на локальном сервере Denwer

Tags: веб-программирование, denwer

Вместо сайта вылезает This domain is for sale! Сайт стоит на вордпресс. Кэш чистил, все перезапускал, буквально 5 минут назад все было нормально. На всякий случай замазал всё, а то за рекламу еще посчитают. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скорее всего порт не правильно настроен и сервер не заменяет URL на локальный. Можно попробовать поменять порт. в FAQ на сайте денвер пишет --- * Вы можете «перевесить» Денвер на другой порт. К примеру, если вы хотите использовать порт 8080, то исправьте в /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf строчку $&{port:-80} на $&{port:-8080}. В этом случае адреса локальных хостов будут выглядеть примерно так: http://localhost:8080/ * http://www.denwer.ru/faq/other.html здесь можете почитать подробнее.

Comment: попробуйте еще переименовать сайт например `wptest.loc` или `test.com1`

Comment: Ну домен ведь и в самом деле продаётся, непонятно в чём вопрос

Comment: Спасибо всем, проблема решена благодаря Максиму. В файле hosts не было записи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denwer должен был добавить этот домен в файл:

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Но видимо по каким то причинам не добавил.

Должна быть запись вида:

`127.0.0.1 wptest.ru`